# Spring Data JPA and Connection Pooling

Tags: oracle, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, connection-pooling

I have a RESTful web application which stores data against Oracle and the stack is Spring-Data-Jpa and Hibernate.

We have implemented connection pooling using Oracle UCP, but it does not seem to work. There were 1000s of connections in the DB for our NFT tests.

My config is as shown below

```
@Bean
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() throws IllegalStateException, SQLException {
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    entityManagerFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource());
    entityManagerFactoryBean.setPersistenceProviderClass(HibernatePersistenceProvider.class);
    entityManagerFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan(env.getRequiredProperty(ENTITYMANAGER_PACKAGES_TO_SCAN));
    entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaProperties(hibProperties());         
    return entityManagerFactoryBean;
}

@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() throws IllegalStateException, SQLException {
    PoolDataSource dataSource = PoolDataSourceFactory.getPoolDataSource();

    dataSource.setConnectionFactoryClassName(env.getRequiredProperty(DB_CONNECTION_FACTORY_CLASS_NAME));
    dataSource.setURL(env.getRequiredProperty(DATABASE_URL));
    dataSource.setUser(env.getRequiredProperty(DATABASE_USERNAME));
    dataSource.setPassword(env.getRequiredProperty(DATABASE_PASSWORD));
    dataSource.setMinPoolSize(Integer.parseInt(env.getRequiredProperty(DATABASE_CONNECTION_MIN_POOL_SIZE)));
    dataSource.setMaxPoolSize(Integer.parseInt(env.getRequiredProperty(DATABASE_CONNECTION_MAX_POOL_SIZE)));
    dataSource.setInitialPoolSize(Integer.parseInt(env.getRequiredProperty(DATABASE_CONNECTION_INITIAL_POOL_SIZE)));

    return dataSource;
}    


private Properties hibProperties() {
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.put(HIBERNATE_DIALECT, env.getRequiredProperty(HIBERNATE_DIALECT));
    properties.put(HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL, env.getRequiredProperty(HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL));
    /*properties.put(HIBERNATE_NAMING_STRATEGY, env.getRequiredProperty(HIBERNATE_NAMING_STRATEGY));*/
    return properties;
}
```

Let me know if there is another config I should be using here, such that a new session is not created all the time.

Thanks

Kris

Answer (score 0):

It would seem that a DataSource gets created for each thread and centralising the datasource in the Jetty config sorted the problem.

[jetty and Oracle Connection Pooling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44625185/jetty-and-oracle-connection-pooling/)